# Установить цвет в hsv

Tags: canvas, javascript

Нужно задавать цвет фона для канвы в hsv, делал так

http://jsfiddle.net/CyBer_UA/yvcGk/3/

```
var canva = document.getElementById('cn'),
  tx = canva.getContext('2d');

  canva.width = 300;
  canva.height = 300;

  ctx.fillStyle = 'hsv(132,93,98)';  
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
```

но постоянно черный фон, я делал что то не так или нужно конвертировать цвет в rgb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hsv` - не [валидный](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp) метод для задания цвета в CSS